# Convert GLB with animation to USD format?

Tags: animation, three.js, gltf, usdz

I am working with threejs library. I want to convert glb animation file format to usda animation format? İs there any way/library to do it.  Any answer would be helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

three.js provides [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=gltf#webgl_loader_gltf) and [USDZExporter](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=usd#misc_exporter_usdz), but the USDZ exporter does not support animation at this time. I'm not aware of any JavaScript USDZ exporter that does, currently.

Beyond that, your best option would be to use a non-web tool like [USD from glTF](https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf), which must be run on your computer or a server that you can install software on.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it :)

Comment: @don-mccurdy Have you found that USD from glTF will support animation?

Comment: @KDP the project readme would be the most current place to find that information, but currently it supports rigid and skinned animation. iOS Quick Look did not support morph targets as of that writing.